# Virtual Hosts, apache, mod-jk and tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, virtualhost, mod-jk

I have a tomcat(running on 8080) application on my cent os server and i can access it with the url:

```
SERVER_IP:8080/myapp
```

and I have my admin panel on

```
SERVER_IP:8080/myapp/admin
```

and I have an apache server running on port 80.

I have two domains :

```
www.myapp.com
admin.myapp.com
```

I've managed to configure tomcat, mod_jk and apache server such that admin.myapp.com url opens the tomcat home page(SERVER_IP:8080).

But what I want is to make admin.myapp.com url to open SERVER_IP:8080/myapp/admin and www.myapp.com to open SERVER_IP:8080/myapp.

I need to make apache know when a request came to admin.myapp.com, it should know to redirect the request to SERVER_IP:8080/myapp/admin. Something is missing obviously.

Here are my configurations :

httpd.conf (admin.myapp.com.conf actually because it is created by plesk panel but i think it's irrevelant)

```
<VirtualHost SERVER_IP:80 >
    ServerName "admin.myapp.com:80"
    ServerAlias "www.admin.myapp.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.admin.myapp.co"
    ServerAdmin "cuneyty@mycompany.com"
    UseCanonicalName Off

    JkMount / ajp13
    JkMount /* ajp13

    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_jk.conf

```
# Load mod_jk module
# Update this path to match your modules location
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

# Where to find workers.properties
# Update this path to match your conf directory location
JkWorkersFile /usr/local/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties

# Where to put jk logs
# Update this path to match your logs directory location
JkLogFile /usr/local/tomcat7/logs/mod_jk.log

# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
```

workers.properties

```
# Define 1 real worker named ajp13
worker.list=ajp13

# Set properties for worker named ajp13 to use ajp13 protocol,
# and run on port 8009
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=300
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can change the path part of the URL with mod_jk.  If you want to use mod_jk, you'd need to rewrite the URL first so that the path part of the URL matches the expected path on the backend.  Other option is use mod_proxy, as you found out.  It's more flexible in this area.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured that out using mod_proxy instead of mod_jk and adding these lines :

```
ProxyPass / http:// SERVER_IP:8080/ 
ProxyPass /myapp/ http:// SERVER_IP:8080/myapp
```

And this line for cookies :

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp /"
```